# How to return values from C/++ functions correctly?

Tags: c++, c, return

I have made some app and the method im using is this:

```
INT name(char *one,char *two,char buffer[]){
memcpy(buffer,"omg",4);//or using std::string::copy ... that's how I actually return value
...}
```

and I call it like:

```
char returned[255];    
name(first,second,returned);
printf/cout;
```

Everything is fine. Now ***my question is***, is this method terrible or a disaster? Also, what is going on with allocated memory for 255 chars, I mean is there a way to re-allocate it somehow to save memory a little?

This is so called pass-by-reference, in either case I have to return multiple values (from 2 to 10). If I would need only 1 I would use **return buffer** with **static** type I guess.

Thanks. Write your favourite methods please while I read similar questions to this one hehe.

Comment: the answer is different for C and C++, which one do you want?

Comment: both :) coz I have to return char array which is C style :)

Answer (score 3):

Just use a return value.

```
std::string name(const std::string& one, const std::string& two)
{
    return "omg";
}
```

If you need to return a variable number of values, return a vector:

```
std::vector<std::string> name(const std::string& one, const std::string& two)
{
    std::vector ret;
    ret.push_back("omg1");
    ret.push_back("omg2");
    ret.push_back("omg3");
    return ret;
}
```

If you need to return a fixed number of values, use pass-by-reference like you suggested.

```
void name(const std::string& one, const std::string& two, std::string& ret1, std::string& ret2)
{
    ret1 = "omg1";
    ret2 = "omg2";
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why is using "const" good practice and where should I use it always? Nice answer btw. But as usual I ask question the wront way, function is type INT coz I want to know if it succeeded or not, and I have to return char array ... so string.c_str() can do the trick on your example right?

Comment: For multiple return values, you could also return a `tuple`.

Answer (score 2):

In C++ you would probably return an std::string and throw an exception instead of returning an INT (?).

Comment: exception in case of failure ? hmm got some example?

Answer (score 1):

Your function is a disaster, since one can easily execute a buffer overflow attack on it.

If you use C++, you could do the following:

```
void name(std::string one, std::string& two, std::string& buffer) {
    buffer = "omg";
....}
```

Then you can just call it like:

```
std::string one, two, buffer;
name(one, two, buffer);
```

Comment: Why is one not a reference but two is one? Why is one and two not a ref to const?

Comment: And the resulting string should be just returned by value.

Answer (score 1):

For C you should pass the size of the buffer along with the pointer to it. Passing an array as a param reduces it to a pointer, which does not contain any information about the size of the memory it points to. Something like this:

```
int name(char *one, char *two, char *buffer, size_t len);
```

and call it like this:

```
char returned[255];
int result = name("one", "two", returned, sizeof returned);
```

For C++ you should use std::string which takes care of it all for you, like others have said.

Comment: Actually passing an array as a param in C works just fine, if it's of type char arr[], sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]) would give you the correct size but if it is of type char * then it will just be a pointer.

Comment: @Jesus: Passing an array works fine, but the information about its size is lost. `sizeof(arr)` in your case will return the size of a pointer, not the size of all the elements occupied by the array together.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in this case `returned` is allocated on the stack, so surely you can't just `free` it (I don't know if you can `delete` it in C++). Just re-use it.

Maybe in this case, returning a pointer to the array would be better.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking C++ - That's pretty bad. Using std::strings, you can do the same thing:

```
void name(const string &first, const string &second, string &returned) {
    returned = first + second + "omg"; // Or something else
}
```

And calling it:

```
string f = "one", s = "two", r;
name(f, s, r);
cout << r; // 'R' now contains "onetwoomg"
```

Although 'mutating' things like this isn't very C++. In C it's used a lot, but in C++ you generally assign to a returned value rather than pass by non-const reference.